ruby - ovirtsdk4 Error during SSO authentication, access_denied: Cannot authenticate user
Ruby ovirt-engine-sdk is not working after my mac update. It was working before update and it not working after mac update
Current mac version: Sonama - Version 14.6.1
I tried installing them gem with following command:
gem install ovirt-engine-sdk -v4.6.0 -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=incompatible-function-pointer-types -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"

ruby-3.0.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0/lib/ovirtsdk4/connection.rb:476:in `create_access_token': Error during SSO authentication: access_denied: Cannot authenticate user 'user@domain.com': Unable to log in. **Verify your login information or contact the system administrator.. (OvirtSDK4::AuthError)**
    from /Users/sh077503/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0/lib/ovirtsdk4/connection.rb:646:in `internal_send'
    from /Users/sh077503/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0/lib/ovirtsdk4/connection.rb:202:in `block in send'
    from /Users/sh077503/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0/lib/ovirtsdk4/connection.rb:202:in `synchronize'
    from /Users/sh077503/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0/lib/ovirtsdk4/connection.rb:202:in `send'
    from /Users/sh077503/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0/lib/ovirtsdk4/service.rb:194:in `internal_get'
    from /Users/sh077503/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.6.0/lib/ovirtsdk4/services.rb:36365:in `list


connection = OvirtSDK4::Connection.new(
  url:      'https://xxx.example.com/ovirt-engine/api',
  username: 'xxx@domain.com',
  password: 'xxx',
  debug:    true,
  insecure: true
)

